# Explanation of Z transform table

Tags: z-transform

I want to ask what is the Z transformation of n? 
How can be n,  transformated  into z/(z-1)^2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For $|z| < 1$  $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n} =  \frac{1}{1-z}, \qquad f'(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n z^{n-1}$$
Thus for $|z^{-1}| < 1$
$$\mathcal{Z}[n 1_{n \ge 0}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n z^{-n} = z^{-1}f'(z^{-1}) = \frac{z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^2} = \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$$

Comment: I'm still don't understand, can you explain it more clearly please, or can you give some external link about z transform of n, thank you

Comment: @Rizalmaulana Are you kidding ?